# ¿Cómo aplicar una alineación de elemento div en todos los tamaños de pantallas menos en el más pequeño en bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

estoy trabajando con la alineación de elementos div en html con bootstrap, me gustaria saber si puedo aplicar una alineación (right) a un elemento div en los tamaños de pantalla **sm**, **md**, **lg** y **xl** y en el más pequeño, osea **xs**, aplicar una alineación a la izquierza (left). Tengo el div con la clase así:

```
<div class="float-sm-right float-md-right float-lg-right float-xl-right float-xs-left"> ... Contenido </div>
```

Me funciona así perfectamente pero tengo que especificar en todos los tamaños, la pregunta es si habrá una clase para aplicar un tamaño en todos (los mencionados) menos **xs** al cual como indico quiero alinearlo a la izquierda.

Comment: nop, tendrías que crearla tu

Comment: Como tal tendrías que crearlo, puedes hacer uso de `@media` dentro de tu script para añadir un tamaño en particular o varios tamaños para ciertos tamaños de pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto una idea fácil para implementar tu estilo. Solamente crea tu propio y único estilo `.mi-float` y con esto trabaja en tu propio y nuevo @media querie para el `float: left`.

Dijiste que en **xs** seria una excepción. Pero este xs no se que @media es en Bootstrap 4; porque el mínimo es de 576px (para los móviles). Como las @media en Bootstrap indican `min-width: 576px`, tu @media podría ser de `max-width: 575px`, de la siguiente manera:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .mi-float {
        float: left !important
    }
}
```

(No debe ser 576px, porque esto es el mínimo de Bootstrap 4, y hará conflicto. Debe ser 575px)!

Ésta @media funcionara menor a 576px (el mínimo de Bootstrap 4). Solamente en ésta @media declara tu estilo `float: left`.

**Los demás, `float: right`, no declares dentro de ningún @media (porque Bootstrap 4 ya tiene definido).**

Por su puesto, en tu HTML sería simplemente `mi-float`:

```
<div class="float-sm-right float-md-right float-lg-right float-xl-right float-xs-left mi-float"> ... Contenido </div>
```

A continuación, por si necesitas, agrego los @media de Bootstrap 4 que encontré:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .float-sm-right {
        float: right !important
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .float-md-right {
        float: right !important
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .float-lg-right {
        float: right !important
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .float-xl-right {
        float: right !important
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo Muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda, me será de gran utilidad.

Comment: Ok. Solamente falta que marques como respuesta aceptada. Para que la respuesta sirva a otros.

Comment: jejejej listo lo acabo de hacer, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no lo sabía.

Comment: Bien gracias. Eso es para saber que tu pregunta ya tubo una respuesta solucionada. Y servirá para otros que busquen la misma solución.

Comment: Cualquier duda o problemas que tenga con algún código, simplemente realiza una nueva pregunta.